# c++ call graph, but as text

Tags: c++, methods, hierarchy, doxygen, call-graph

For a given method (eg. Settings.cpp getSettingByName()), I would like to get a **text** representation of the call graph. I've heard doxygen can generate an image of the call graph, I'm more interested in a text output.

For example, if I gave it "Settings.cpp getMethodByName" it would return:

```
Settings.cpp getSettingByName();
    SettingsWrapper.cpp getMaximumSpeed();
        ECU.cpp monitorSpeed();
            Operate.cpp runECU();
                Main.cpp run();
        CruiseControl.cpp accelerate();
            Operate.cpp runCruiseControl();
                Main.cpp run();
        Radio.cpp playApplauseThroughSpeakers();
            Operate.cpp runStereo();
                Main.cpp run();
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks, Fidel

ps. don't freak about the code, it's just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any prebuilt solutions for that.

However, Doxygen will in fact generate the (image) call graph by building a GraphViz dot file for the call graph. The Dot format is raw text and very simple, so you might find it easiest to let Doxygen run, and parse the generated .dot files yourself.

Comment: If you code is template heavy, you won't have much luck with the Doxygen call-graph though.

Comment: Thanks pmr, shall consider that.

Comment: Padawan, the doxygen doco is a bit vague when it comes to generate the DOT file. Do you know how to do it? Do I need dot installed and HAVE_DOT = YES?

Comment: If you're on Windows, definitely check out Doxywizard, which lists all Doxygen flags on a separate tab. You want HAVE_DOT and CALL_GRAPH activated as well as set the correct bin directory for Graphviz.

Comment: to leave dot files -  DOT_CLEANUP=NO

Answer (score 3):

It is super late, but I am going to mention it anyways.

For C source files, you can definitely use [cflow](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/). It will shows you the textual output for C files as you mentioned it.

However, unfortunately, when I tried it out for C++, the output was almost garbage. Keep in mind that I didn't investigate its C++ feature thoroughly and I only was looking to parse C files. It has an option flag called `--cpp` though that gets a C Preprocessor.